# Prove that a right-continuous stochastic process is product measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let

- $X=(X_t,t\ge 0$ be a real-valued stochastic process on a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ with almost surely right-continuous paths
- $\mathbb{F}:=(\mathcal{F}_t,t\ge 0)$ be a filtraiton on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ and $X$ be adapted to $\mathbb{F}$

I want to show, that for all $t\ge 0$ $$\Omega\times [0,t]\to\mathbb{R}\;,\;\;\;(\omega,s)\mapsto X_s(\omega)\tag{1}$$ is $\mathcal{F}_t\otimes\mathcal{B}\left([0,t]\right)$-measurable.

---

Let $$A_k^{(n)}:=\left[\frac t{2^n}(k-1),\frac t{2^n}k\right]\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\; t_k^{(n)}:=\frac t{2^n}k\;\;\;\;\;\text{for }k=0,\ldots,2^n$$ Moreover, let $$X^{(n)}(\omega,s):=\sum_{k=0}^{2^n}1_{A_k^{(n)}}(s)X_{t_k^{(n)}}(\omega)\;\;\;\text{for }(\omega,s)\in\Omega\times [0,t]\tag{2}$$ Clearly, $X^{(n)}$ is $\mathcal{F}_t\otimes\mathcal{B}\left([0,t]\right)$-measurable and we've got $$X^{(n)}(\omega,s)=X_{t_k^{(n)}}(\omega)\Leftrightarrow s\in A_k^{(n)}\tag{3}$$ How do we need to use the continuity from the right to show $$\lim_{n\to\infty}X^{(n)}(\omega,s)=X_s(\omega)\;\;\;\text{almost surely}\;?\tag{4}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a remark concerning the definition of $X^{(n)}$: Instead of the closed interval $A_k^{(n)} := [t_{k-1}^{(n)},t_k^{(n)}]$ you should use the half-open interval $A_k^{(n)} := (t_{k-1}^{(n)},t_k^{(n)}]$ (otherwise you might run into trouble at the boundary points $\{t_k^{(n)}\}$). Then

$$X^{(n)}(s,\omega) := X_0(\omega) 1_{\{0\}}(s) + \sum_{k=1}^{2^n} 1_{A_k^{(n)}}(s) X_{t_k^{(n)}}(\omega)$$

does the job.

---

Fix $s \in (0,t]$. For any $n \geq 1$, there exists a unique number $k_n \in \{1,\ldots,2^n\}$ such that

$$s \in \bigg( t_{k_n-1}^{(n)}, t_{k_n}^{(n)} \bigg].$$

By definition,

$$X^{(n)}(s,\omega) = X(t_{k_n}^{(n)},\omega).$$

Thus, since $t_{k_n}^{(n)} \to s$ as $n \to \infty$ and $t_{k_n}^{(n)} \geq s$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it follows from the right-continuity that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} X^{(n)}(s,\omega) = \lim_{n \to \infty} X(t_{k_n}^{(n)},\omega) = X_s(\omega).$$

Comment: Is $t_{k_n}^{(n)}\downarrow s$, especially $$t_{k_{n+1}}^{(n+1)}\le t_{k_n}^{(n)}\;,$$ really true?

Comment: @0xbadf00d What I mean by $t_k^{(n)} \downarrow s$ is that $t_k^{(n)} \to s$ as $n \to \infty$ and $t_k^{(n)} \geq s$ (i.e. the sequence converges "from the right" to $s$).

Comment: There are some errors in your answer. The sum in the first equation should run from $1$ to $2^n$ and you don't use $k_n$ in your second equation.

Comment: Thinking about that: Why can't we use $$t_k^{(n)}:=\frac knt$$ instead of $t_k^{(n)}:=\frac k{2^n}t$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Doesn't make any difference, we can also use this one. (And, yeah, I'm sorry, I mixed those two up.)

Comment: @saz hence at the points of discontinuity we have $(s,s]X_{s}$? It looks a little wierd to approximate a right continuous function by a left continuous one. But your argument looks good.

Comment: @user32423 Sorry, but I don't understand your question... what do you mean by "we have "(s,s] X_s"? I don't see any intervals of this form popping up in my answer.

Comment: @saz oh I mean, $lim(t_{k}^{n},t_{k}^{n}]X_{t_{k}^{n}}$ for $t_{k}^{n} ->s$ from the right.

Comment: @saz having $(t_{k_{n}-1}^n,t_{k_{n}}^{n}]$ would lead to a large error at point of discontinuity, say if we have a onesided jum

Comment: @user32423 Why do you think so? Note that we are approximating $s$ from **above** by $t_{k_n}^{(n)}$.

Comment: @saz since if any number less then $s$ belongs to the intervall we get a discontinuity. And since $t_{k_{n}}^{n}->  s$ any number less then any number in the sequence must be less then $s$ or equal to it.

Comment: the intevall must look like $(s,..]$ atleast thats what I am saying. At a point of discontinuity

Comment: @user32423 I'm sorry, but I can't follow your thoughts. In the second part of my answer, I proved that the approximation does the job... so you can either a) why you think that the proof is wrong or b) give me a specific counterexample where the approximations fails.

Comment: @saz actually, there is nothing wrong with having the lower limit approch s from below. Which should be fine at yhe countable number of discont. that we may have. I was messeing things up I think.